# how to combine two JSON array in one JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I am creating some dynamic forms with the help of jquery and JSON and string JSON into html div id. When I want to merge these JSONs into single array, it is not made a correct JSON. Please help me to create this.

**HTML DATA**

```
<div id="dataStore">
<div class="col-md-4" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
<h5>Column 1</h5>
<div id="dataStore1" class="connectedSortable ui-sortable">
  <div id="field1" class="fieldData" style="display:block">
    <div id="titlefield1" class="fieldTitle">field1</div>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove removeButton" id="crossfield1"></span>
    <div id="datafield1" style="visibility:hidden" class="hiddenVis">{"field1":[{"type":"text","label":"dsa","nameid":"das","placeholder":"das","is_req":"1"}]}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="field2" class="fieldData" style="display:block">
    <div id="titlefield2" class="fieldTitle">field2</div>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove removeButton" id="crossfield2"></span>
    <div id="datafield2" style="visibility:hidden" class="hiddenVis">{"field2":[{"type":"text","label":"dsa","nameid":"dsa","placeholder":"dsa","is_req":"0"}]}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
var emptyData1 = '';
$('#dataStore1').find('.hiddenVis').each(function() 
        {
            emptyData1 = emptyData1 + $(this).html();
        });
if(emptyData1!='')
        {
            var json1 = '{"column1"'+':['+emptyData1+"]}";
        }
```

**My Output**

```
{
"column1": [
    {
        "field1": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "dsa",
                "nameid": "das",
                "placeholder": "das",
                "is_req": "1"
            }
        ]
    }{
        "field2": [
            {
                "type": "text",
                "label": "dsa",
                "nameid": "dsa",
                "placeholder": "dsa",
                "is_req": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
"column1": [
    {
        "field1": [
            {
                "type": "email",
                "label": "DSA",
                "nameid": "DAS",
                "placeholder": "dS",
                "is_req": "1"
            }
        ],
        "field2": [
            {
                "type": "Number",
                "label": "dAS",
                "nameid": "DSA",
                "placeholder": "dAS",
                "is_req": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Don't generate JSON manually.

Comment: is there any sense store 'column1' as array with only 1 object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` can help you in this task:

```
var data1 = {};

$('#dataStore1').find('.hiddenVis').each(function() {
    var itemData = JSON.parse($(this).html()); // To javascript object (object).

    for (var key in itemData) {
        data1[key] = itemData[key];
    }
});

var json1 = JSON.stringify({column1: data1}); // Back to JSON (string).
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the outer {} on your html.

```
<div id="datafield1" style="visibility:hidden" class="hiddenVis">"field1":[{"type":"text","label":"dsa","nameid":"das","placeholder":"das","is_req":"1"}]</div>
```

Then add it on the jquery code:

```
var emptyData1 = '';
$('#dataStore1').find('.hiddenVis').each(function() 
    {
        emptyData1 = emptyData1 + $(this).html();
    });
    if(emptyData1!='')
    {
        var json1 = '{"column1"'+':[{'+emptyData1+"}]}";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this slight change in your javascript I hope it will work for you :)

```
   var emptyData1 = '';
            $('#dataStore1').find('.hiddenVis').each(function() 
    {
        emptyData1 = emptyData1 +','+ $(this).html();
    });

    if(emptyData1!='')
    {
        emptyData1 = emptyData1.replace(',', '');
        var json1 = '{"column1"'+':['+emptyData1+"]}";
        console.log(JSON.parse(json1));
        alert(json1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should generate exactly the desired output that you posted:

```
var theObject = {column1: [ {} ]};
$('#dataStore1').find('.hiddenVis').each(function() {
    var nextObject = JSON.parse($(this).html());
    theObject.column1[0][Object.keys(nextObject)[0]] = nextObject[Object.keys(nextObject)[0]]
});

console.log(theObject);
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/k8nm4nrn/)